# How to put a button to go to other applications?

Tags: java, android

I have this code to take you to other applications from my page.

```
Button more_apps = (Button)findViewById(R.id.more_apps);
        more_apps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent more_apps = new Intent();
                more_apps.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                more_apps.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                more_apps.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=****"));
                startActivity(more_apps);
            }
        });
```

No problem other than that sometimes google play rejects the app and sends me a picture indicating that the 'more apps' button is promoting other apps. ..Bla bla bla

So I had an idea: when you click on the button, a confirmation message appears to go “yes” or “no”, and if you press “yes” it directs you to the link, and pressing “no” remains in the application.

How can this be achieved please

Comment: For your idea, use Alertdialog before navigating the user to another application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to show a dialog is to build using the `AlertDialog.Builder()`.

You can use the following method from some random **Util Class** and just pass the arguments:

```java
public static AlertDialog createAlert(String message, String positiveButtonText, DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveListener, String negativeButtonText, DialogInterface.OnClickListener negativeListener, Context context, boolean isCancelable) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(positiveButtonText, positiveListener)
                .setNegativeButton(negativeButtonText, negativeListener)
                .setCancelable(isCancelable)
                .create();
    }
```

And you use it like this:

```java
AlertDialog goToPlayStoreDialog = RandomUtilClass.createAlert(
       "Do you want to see more of my apps?",
       "Yes", positiveListener,
       "No", negativeListener,
       context, false);

goToPlayStoreDialog.show();
```

And here is how a listener is implemented:

```java
DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveListener = (dialog, which) -> {
        **Start intent here**
};
```

As for the negative listener, simply call `dialog.dismiss();`

**Note** that you should implement the listeners **before** creating the dialog :)